# how it is possible to retrieve console --parameter values in php-cli?

Tags: php

When calling a PHP script in console this way:

```
phpscript.php --param1=value --param2=value2
```

How it is possible to retrieve `param1` and `param2` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$argv` is available to your script, but it's easier to use [`getopt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php).

```
$options = getopt("", array("param1:", "param2:"));
```

Comment: PHP is great in that there is a function for everything. PHP also sucks because it has a function for everything. :)